# jQuery Mobile - changing the flipswitch on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I have a disabled flipswitch. When the flipswitch is clicked a popup appears asking the user if they're sure they want to change the flipswitch. If they click yes then they will have to reanswer several questions. I want to be able to change the flipswitch, answer questions, then go back and change the flipswitch again, reanswer questions... etc. For some reason when I click the flipswitch its working on the first click, but the second click it changes it from yes to no (or the other way around) and back. Its almost as if its recording how many times it was clicked.

[Here is a fiddle to show the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/AH6PJ/)

Here is my code:

```
$("#US_toggle").click(function(){ //flipswitch is clicked
  $('#US_Popup').popup('open'); //popup is opened
  $('#US_changeYes').click(function(){
    if($("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").hasClass('ui-flipswitch-active')){                
      $("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").removeClass('ui-flipswitch-active');
    }else{
      $("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").addClass('ui-flipswitch-active');
    };
  });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="US_toggle" class="floatRight">             
    <select name="US_flipswitch" id="US_flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch" data-theme="c" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="off">No</option>
      <option value="on">Yes</option>
    </select>               
</div>
```

Comment: just a suggestion. It will not solve your problem but it will simplify your code. You can use `$("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").toggleClass('ui-flipswitch-active')` instead of the whole hasClass if statment

Comment: Can you show us your HTML markup, or even better create a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I tried your suggestion and unfortunately it didn't remove or add the class.

Comment: @ezanker I added the HTML. I'll try and put together a fiddle.

Comment: @ezanker - [fiddle created](http://jsfiddle.net/AH6PJ/)

Comment: @michelle I dont think you used it right here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AH6PJ/5/) of the code used on the resolved jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the click code to the changeYes button every time the popup is launched. You should only add it once outside of the div click:

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/AH6PJ/1/)**

```
$("#US_toggle").click(function () {
    $('#US_Popup').popup('open');

});

$('#US_changeYes').click(function () {
    if ($("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").hasClass('ui-flipswitch-active')) {
        $("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").removeClass('ui-flipswitch-active');
    } else {
        $("#US_toggle .ui-flipswitch").addClass('ui-flipswitch-active');
    };
});
```

UPDATE: Instead of toggling the classes, it is probably better to toggle the select value and then refresh the flipswitch:

```
$('#US_changeYes').click(function () {
    var curVal = $("#US_flipswitch").val();
    curVal == "off" ? $("#US_flipswitch").val("on").flipswitch("refresh") : $("#US_flipswitch").val("off").flipswitch("refresh");
});
```

> New **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/AH6PJ/3/)**

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much for solving my problem!

Comment: You are welcome. Please see my updated answer, I think it is better code to toggle the select value rather than the classes...